# NEventStore: How does dispatching of undispatched events scale?

Tags: cqrs, neventstore

Even though I have intensely read about the transactional integrity on NEventStore, I cannot grasp how NEventStore would really scale when having many instances of NEventStore wired up.

To summarize my understanding, an Event is added to commits as undispatched, then it publishes to dispatchers and then marked as dispatched.

At the same time, whenever you wire up NEventStore, it goes to look for undispatched events, and then dispatches them and marks the event as dispatched.

But then there must be a short time span when a wiring up of a new event store will see undispatched events which are about to be dispatched (from other stores). The new event store will dispatch the events again.

Think of this architecture:

`Client -> Command Bus -> Command Handler -> EventStore persist -> Dispatch to Event Handlers`

If we have many `Command Handlers` to handle our load, we would also be persisting many events.

If we are often disposing or creating `Command Handlers`, then many EventStores would be wired up and cause dispatching of events already being dispatched.

I understand that consumers of the dispatcher should be idempotent, which is not my issue. My issue is whether we would be providing an unneeded amount of load on the consumers the the command handlers in a high load situation?

Answer (score 3):

This question is really old, but as I just stumbled over it, I'll add my two cents: I don't think you're supposed to wire up a new instance of NEventStore for every instance of a command handler. The NEventStore objects are stateless, so you can use a single instance for your whole process (or `AppDomain`).

So, sure, if you have multiple processes, each of those will wire up a new NEventStore and your scenario might become reality. However, the effect will probably be very small and not hamper scalability too much.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion is acceptable that in this case messages are dispatched multiple times. In fact base on [this doc](https://github.com/NEventStore/NEventStore/wiki/Architectural-Overview#the-dispatcher-interface):

> There is a small possibility during failure scenarios where a set of
>   events may be dispatched but not yet marked as such. This may result
>   in the same set of messages being redispatched. In a message-oriented
>   system, the concept of at-least-once delivery is always something that
>   should be considered and this situation is no different. Message
>   consumers should be made idempotent (potentially by tracking a list of
>   previous messages) to avoid duplicate incoming messages.

So yes, consumers can eventually receive the same message multiple times.

But as Fabian Schmied says I think that you should create (wire up) neventstore only once per application instance, not for each command handler.